# Monetizing YouTube Channel with Videos Containing CC-Licensed Content

Tags: video, youtube, copyright, music

I have a YouTube channel that I eventually hope to earn ad revenue from, however some of my videos use CC BY-NC licensed content.

I realize monetizing those particular videos is off the table (obviously), but does having them prevent me from monetizing my videos that don't have such content (CC BY/royalty-free)?

In other words, can one video with CC BY-NC content taint my entire channel?

I'm still new at this and I want to study up on the best practices for running my channel to avoid doing something I shouldn't.

Answer (score 3):

No, one offending video won't taint your entire channel.  At my workplace, sometimes the youtube algorithms will mistakenly flag some music to which we own the rights as copyright protected.  When such an event occurs, the video is automatically un-monetized, and we are asked to demonstrate that we have rights to the music. The video still plays, we just don't make any money off of it. The rest of the channel is unaffected.

Comment: Ah, okay. In this case, could I choose to turn off monetization for each future video with CC BY-NC content before it goes public, and leave monetization on for the rest without there being problems?

Comment: I've done that, and never had problems with my channels. I've been uploading to YouTube since 2006 and I have about 300 videos. YouTube pays me monthly for my monetized videos and just skips my non-monetized videos, though viewers watch them regularly.